# Using Flow.js in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use [flow.js](https://flowtype.org/) with [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) but I'm running into issues getting it to work in .vue files.

I ran `vue init webpack`, `npm install -g flow-bin`, and then `npm install` and `npm run dev`.

I was able to ignore the erroring files in my node_modules in my .flowconfig, but when I try to add `// @flow` to the top of my src/main.js file I get the following error

```
src/main.js:3
  3: import App from './App';
                     ^^^^^^^ ./App. Required module not found
```

I've tried adding `// @flow` notation to my src/App.vue file and I've tried adding src/App.vue to `[include]` in .flowconfig but I still get the error.

I'd like to avoid stubbing .vue files as there's not much of a point of using flow if most of the files you have js in won't be able to use them.

Is there a way to use flow with vue?

Comment: Are you using Babel?

Comment: i'm using the default vuejs webpack setup which uses babel with the es6 preset

Comment: @DanielNill did you found any answers?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `.vue` as an extension in your Webpack resolve config.

Try adding the following to `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".vue"]
  }
};
```

[See the documentation for `resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions)

If that doesn't work and depending on what you're using your import for you can try breaking your script out of the `.vue` file. Use the `src` attribute to reference an external file and then import that independent script directly inside the script you need to reference it from.

Example:

**foo.vue**

```
<script src="./foo.js"></script>
<template>
  ...
</template>
```

**bar.vue**

```
<script>
  import Foo from './foo.js';
  // do something with the default export of foo.js
</script>
<template>
  ...
</template>
```

[See the documentation for the `src` attribute](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html#src-imports)